# JitPack and local development

Tags: jitpack

We are using JitPack for development, as we have several modules, and it is very easy to propagate changes across.

However, if I want to build something locally, I have an issue. We used to install artifact with gradle, so I was able to build some change locally, install it in the my local maven repo, and then us everywhere.

Now I can't do that. Instead, I must send my branch to upstream and then I can use it everywhere. Which is not what I want, to pollute upstream with my playground.

Is there a way to use JitPack and still to be able to use local maven repo optionally when I made a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first make sure your local gradle build produces the same groupId as jitpack does. Either set `group = 'com.github....'` in your local gradle build or [configure jitpack to use your real domain name](https://jitpack.io/docs/#custom-domain-name).

Secondly configure your gradle builds to prefer your local maven repo over jitpack:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Comment: 'group' is not enough; `version` has to be set to name of the branch + eg `-SNAPSHOT`